# Windows Inject a standard C FILE Structure into A Running Process

Tags: c++, c, windows, windows-ce

I had sort of an odd idea and was wondering whether it would be possible. Here's a rough outline of my plan.

**Scenario:** An application loads and interprets values from a config file at startup. I want to fuzz the application via the config file, without rewriting the config file.

**Note:** The config file is closed later on in the program, and the function that opens the config file is used to open various other files, so I do not want to hook this function. While `SetKMode()` and `SetProcPermissions()` are used here, answers that apply to Windows in general are just as helpful as **Windows CE** answers.

**Plan:**

1. Attain debug privileges over this process via SetKMode() and SetProcPermissions and attach a debugger via DebugActiveProcess()
2. Break after the function that loads the file returns
3. Create a temporary modified version of the file and open it in the parent process
4. Use `VirtualAlloc()` to allocate space for the FILE structure in the debugee
5. Transfer the entire FILE structure for the temporary file to the debugee using `WriteProcessMemory()`
6. Swap the pointer for the config file loaded by the debuggee to the pointer for the temporary file
7. Allow the debugee to run the file
8. Before the debugee closes the file, copy the old pointer for the original config file back to the new pointer so that it closes the correct file

Would the debugger be able to read the file? Would the parent be able to close the file after it's finished?

**Edit:**

Transferring the old pointer back to the debugee every time it tries to close the file no longer seems like a good solution after some RE, so on top of my current question I have an additional question: Would the debugee be able to close the file the debugger opened? Would that be a problem? And would the fact that the original file isn't closed properly be a problem?

**Edit:**

Sorry I'm a dummy who forgot that if I'm going through the trouble of injecting all this I can just inject a new filename and swap the pointer long before the call to fopen.

Comment: It seems unlikely that creating a copy of the parent process's `FILE` structure in the child process would be sufficient to confer access to the open file.  I feel confident in saying that it would not be sufficient in Linux or macOS, but I don't know Windows architecture well enough to have the same level of confidence there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entire file is loaded into memory and then parsed, I would hook whatever function loads the file data into memory, use a conditional to check the filename so you're only executing your code after the correct file is loaded into memory by checking the filename.  Then I would perform my fuzzing by modifying the file data in memory and then return execution to the target process before the file dats is then parsed.  In this manner you aren't touching any file permissions, only memory.

To automate it create a "loader' which executes the target process, injects, executes your hook and then checks for crash or other unwanted behavior.